# C# and Excel Interop issue, Saving the excel file not smooth

Tags: c#, interop, excel-interop

I could Open and Write to the excel file, but when I try to save the file by passing a path to it, the save operation prompts with the Save dialog. I was expecting it to quitely Save the file at the specified path

The code is as below:

```
excelApp.Save(exportToDirectory);
excelApp.Quit();
```

where, **exportToDirectory** is: "C:\files\strings.xlsx".

PS: I have already checked with the excel version and similar issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `Workbook.SaveAs` instead of `Application.Save`:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(missing);
...
wb.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\test.xlsx", missing, missing, missing, missing,
          missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
          missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Comment: Any idea what the numerical value for Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive is?  I need to pass this to this function in a windows script file.

Comment: @MrVimes Totally late to the party for you, however here they are for future reference: `public enum XlSaveAsAccessMode
    {
        xlNoChange = 1,
        xlShared = 2,
        xlExclusive = 3
    }`

Answer (score 15):

Setting the following properties might also help:

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
excelApp.Visible = false;
excelApp.UserControl = false;
excelApp.Interactive = false;
```

Comment: I try a lot of solution but this was the only one that works like it should! Very useful! Tks!!

Answer (score 3):

just set the **ActiveWorkbook.Saved** *property* to **true**  and you can  Quit() without any Dialog box;

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's how Microsoft does it:

```
// Save the Workbook and quit Excel.
m_objBook.SaveAs(m_strSampleFolder + "Book1.xls", m_objOpt, m_objOpt, 
    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
    m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
m_objBook.Close(false, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
m_objExcel.Quit();
```

See one of their [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023)s.

Answer (score 1):

`ExcelApp.Interactive = false` suppresses any dialog box.

`excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(exportDirectory)`

Answer (score 1):

I found `excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.save()` which can save the file, then I can quit without for asking.

Answer (score 1):

`myBook.Saved = true;`
`myBook.SaveCopyAs(xlsFileName);`
`myBook.Close(null, null, null);`
`myExcel.Workbooks.Close();`
`myExcel.Quit();`

Comment: This worked best for me and not the highest rated answers. What I liked about this solution is that it didn't affect other Excel files opened by user.