# Matlab Actxserver :How could I terminate process opened by actxserver in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, com, office-interop

I want to open and close an Excel file in MATLAB.
I have tried [the code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/244473) below, but it failed on closing process with [actxserver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html)

```
h.WorkBooks.Item(wbkname).Close;
```

here is my code for this issue, how can I terminate the excel file?

```
.Quit
.delete
```

I also tried to close excel file via VBA sub-module, but it gives me an error message:

```
fullFileName  = [pwd '\KOSPI200_1월.xlsm'];
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application'); 
file = excel.Workbooks.Open(fullFileName);
excel.Run('jongho_bot_initial');
excel.Run('jongho_bot_loop',2);
```

Comment: And the error message is... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that creates a new spreadsheet, write some values, save the file and exit. The Excel process is cleanly terminated at the end.

```
% create Excel COM server
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excel.Visible = true;  % make the window visible

% create new workbook
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();

% get "Sheet1" and activate it
sheet = wb.Sheets.Item(1);
sheet.Activate();

% select a 5x5 range, and fill it with some numeric values
sheet.Range('A1:E5').Value = num2cell(magic(5));

% save spreadsheet file
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;  % overwrite file without prompts
wb.SaveAs(fullfile(pwd(),'myfile.xlsx'));

% close spreadsheet
wb.Close(false);

% quit Excel
excel.Quit();

% delete handles and clear variables
delete(excel);
clear sheet wb excel
```

You might additionally want to set [certain properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/785704/97160) appropriately, if you want the automation to be performed in the background with no user interaction:

```
excel.Visible = false;         % invisible Excel window
excel.ScreenUpdating = false;  % turn off screen update to run faster 
excel.Interactive = false;     % non-interactive mode, with no keyboard/mouse
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;   % no prompts or alert messages
excel.UserControl = false;     % object freed when reference count reaches zero
```