# MatLab: Iterating dynamically through Cells with Excel COM Add-In

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, structure

First of all thanks a lot, for very good answers that I have found here in other topics in the past.

Now to a new challenge:

I am currently working with the COM Add-In in Matlab, i.e. I am reading a Excel Workbook and extracting the Color Property:

```
excelapp = actxserver('Excel.Application');   %connect to excel
workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open('Solutions.xls');        
worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Item(1);                        
ColorValue_Solutions=worksheet.Range('N2').Interior.Color;
```

Now, I want to do this for cells in the Range A1 up to J222, for which I would like to dynmaically loop through the Range property, letting the programm read each cell individually and then taking out the color proerty. For example:

```
Columns = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};

for j = 1:length(Columns)          
   for i = 1:222

worksheet.(char( strcat('Range(''',Columns(j), num2str(i), ''')') )).Interior.Color

   end
end
```

This, however, results in an error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'Range('A1')'.
```

I guess the problem is in the combination of interpreting a string with an included string, i.e. Range('A1').

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I asked a similar question. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35241610/3599179), maybe you will find it helpful.

The following code should do what you want:

You can see how the [`Interior.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx) property is extracted from every cell by first getting a `Cell` object, then accessing the `Interior` object of that `Cell` and finally getting the `Color` property of that `Interior` object. The `Color` property is a color integer defined by Microsoft (you can learn more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355244.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920172/3599179)), I store that value in a matrix (`M`). In order to repeat this process through the specified range of cells, I use a nested loop, like you were doing already. Once the process is finished, I display the contents of `M`.

```
excelapp = actxserver('Excel.Application');    % Start Excel as ActiveX server.
workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open('Solutions.xls');    % Open Excel workbook.
worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Item(1);           % Get the sheet object (sheet #1).

ncols = 10;             % From column A to J.
nrows = 222;            % From row 1 to 222.
M(nrows, ncols) = 0;    % Preallocate matrix M.

for col = 1:ncols                              % Loop through every column.
    for row = 1:nrows                          % Loop through every row.
        cell = get(worksheet, 'Cells', row, col);   % Get the cell object.
        interior = cell.Interior;              % Get the interior object.
        colorint = get(interior, 'Color');     % Get the color integer property.
        M(row, col) = colorint;                % Store color integer in matrix M.
    end
end

disp(M);    % Display matrix M with the color integer information.
```

Remember to close the connection when you are finished. You can learn how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24576193/3599179) and [here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94822-are-there-any-examples-that-show-how-to-use-the-activex-automation-interface-to-connect-matlab-to-ex).